# Batch request with Google Cloud Storage python client

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I can't find any examples on how to use the python google cloud storage's batch functionality.  I see it exists [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/storage/google/cloud/storage/batch.py).

I'd love a concrete example.  Let's say I want to delete a bunch of blobs with a given prefix.  I'd start getting the list of blobs as follows

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('my_bucket_name')
blobs_to_delete = bucket.list_blobs(prefix="my/prefix/here")

# how do I delete the blobs in blobs_to_delete in a single batch?

# bonus: if I have more than 100 blobs to delete, handle the limitation
#        that a batch can only handle 100 operations
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Just send all the requests within the [`batch()` context manager](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storage/client.html#google.cloud.storage.client.Client.batch) (available in the `google-cloud-python` library)

Try this example:

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('my_bucket_name')
# Accumulate the iterated results in a list prior to issuing
# batch within the context manager
blobs_to_delete = [blob for blob in bucket.list_blobs(prefix="my/prefix/here")]

# Use the batch context manager to delete all the blobs    
with storage_client.batch():
    for blob in blobs_to_delete:
        blob.delete()
```

You only need to worry about the 100 items per batch if you're using the REST APIs directly. The [`batch()` context manager](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storage/client.html#google.cloud.storage.client.Client.batch) automatically takes care of this restriction and will issue multiple batch requests if needed.

Comment: where in the documentation does it mention that its a context manager?

Comment: @NKijak That fact is not mentioned in the documentation, but if you look at the [source](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/batch.html#Batch), you can see the __enter__ and __exit__ methods. By the way, from my usage, the context manager will throw an exception if you exceed the max batch size (currently 1000), so you do need to keep track of the number of items per batch.

Comment: I'm using code almost exactly like this; but I have several thousand file to process so I am  chunking them https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/227539.  But at the end of each batch, I get a ValueError "No deferred requests" thrown.  What have I missed that might be causing this exception?  (I now catch it and ignore it, and things seem to be working ok)